# Is there a way to get the "Item-level Permissions" section when creating a new list based on the "Issue Tracking" list template

Tags: 2013, content-type, custom-list, issue-tracking

i am working on a sharepoint enterprise server 2013. and most of the lists i have been creating were based on the "Issue Tracking" list. since the issue tracking list provides a good starting point for me and it have a powerful ability to add comment and track them as follow:-

[image]

Today i was checking how creating a new list based on the built-in "Custom List" will look like.. i check different setting and i find an important section for the custom List named "Item-Level Permission" which is not provided inside the Issue tracking list:-

[image]

so can anyone adivce on these two points:-

- why i did not get the same "Item Level permission" section when i created a new issue tracking list , same as the one i get when creating a new custom list?
- as i mentioned before i uses the issue tracking list ,, because it provide a comment field which allow users to add comments on each version and also allow users to check previous versions of the item... so can i add such a column inside a new Custom list? . so in this case i can have the comment field + the item-level permission ??

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44381/discussion-on-question-by-john-g-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-item-level-permissio).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Comment field with Append to Text**

The Comments column in an Issues list uses the Append Changes to Existing Text setting.  This setting is available for Multiple lines of text column types.  Instructions for enabling the setting are below.

1. Go to List Settings (or Library Settings).
2. In the Columns section, click Create column.
3. Name your column, and select Multiple lines of text.
4. In the Additional Column Settings section, select Yes for Append Changes to Existing Text.

**NOTE:**  Existing columns can have the feature enabled, but if the column has been in use, you may lose existing column data by enabling the setting.

**Item-Level Permission Setting**

The Item-Level Permissions setting is not available in Issues list templates.  What is odd about this feature missing from the Issue template, is that every other major list type – Tasks, Discussion Board, Custom – all have the setting available in the Advanced Settings section.

Because so many other list templates provide the setting, I would think that a PowerShell script is floating around out there that would enable the feature.  I did a cursory check on your behalf, but was unable to find any information.  The only blogs I found outlined how to change item level permissions using a Designer workflow (using the Impersonator Step, and the following List Actions:  Remove List Item Permissions and Replace List Item permissions), which is not what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44488/discussion-on-answer-by-jenny-hersko-is-there-a-way-to-get-the-item-level-permi).

Answer (score 6):

**To have BOTH assigned to emails and item-level permissions:**

You can use a Tasks list and change the content type to Issues.

First create a list from the Tasks template. Go to List Setting >> Advanced Settings, select "Yes" for "Allow management of content types?" (Notice on that screen you have Item-level permissions, and e-mail notification.) Back at List Settings, click "Add from existing site content types" and select Issue. Remove the other content types by selecting them and clicking "Delete this content type." (Optionally, go back into advanced settings and change "Allow management of content types?" back to "No.")

Now your list will contain Issues, but also allow Item-Level permissions.

Comment: if i got your point correctly ,,, you want me to start with the Task template instead of the custom list template  to get the " assigned to emails" ,, is this correct ? now in my case if i want to send emails to assigned to users ,, i think i will create a new workflow for this instead of relying on the default email template used... so i do not think it is a big deal...

Comment: This is the way to get the functionality of the issues list, but still have the item-level permissions. If you don't need that functionality, then it doesn't matter what template you start from.

Comment: but at the end creating a new document library and new issue tracking list will not allow me to have "Item-level" permissions even using powershell.. is this correct ?

Comment: A document library will never allow you to have item-level permissions. A list created from a Task list but containing Issue content type will let you have item-level permissions (without having to run any powershell). A list created from the Issue Tracking template will not allow item-level permissions.

Comment: You could create a custom list template by following the steps I provided, then saving that list as a template. Then you'd only have to go through these steps once.

Comment: You can have item-level permission in document library!! Just need to modify "Permission for this document library", stop inheriting permissions, then assign permission for each document manually.

Comment: @YogaPanda We're not talking about security/permissions settings. There's an option in lists to limit item permissions to only allow users to read and/or edit items they created. It's under List Settings >> Advanced Settings

Comment: @YogaPanda i think Erin is correct and her answer will not misleading visitors,assuming visitors will first read my question carefully., you can not have "Item-Level permission" setting for a document library or an issue tracking,,what you are mentioning is different .. my question is about having "Item-level permission" settings section.. i am not asking if it is possible to have independent security setting for a document or item ... this is a different story.. now visitors need to read the question before start reading Erin or other answers !!

Answer (score 3):

The Issue Tracking List is different from Custom List .
Where its default `WriteSecurity is 1` and can't be changed.

**The main reason for that** this list doesn't have an Item Permission Level in its Advanced settings List as Shown below.

[image]

**Not Like The Custom List Item Level Permissions Settings.**

[image]

**[workaround]**

- Create A custom list.
- go to advanced settings . > Allow content types.
- go to add an existing content types Select > list group > Issues.
- Set it as default.

[image]

- now you can use issue content type with a custom list as Issue Tracking List With Item Permission Level.

[image]

Dear John I think you asked a similar question before at [Modify the WriteSecurity property for an Issue Tracking List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191493/modify-the-writesecurity-property-for-an-issue-tracking-list/191500#191500)