# Modify the WriteSecurity property for an Issue Tracking List

Tags: 2013, list, powershell

I am working on an issue tracking list inside SharePoint 2013 and I want to set the `WriteSecurity` for the list to be = 2.

So I run the following script:

```
$web = get-spweb "http://t*******1/"
$spList = $web.lists["Issue T*****"]
$spList.WriteSecurity=2
$spList.Update()
```

Now I did not get any error, but the effect is not reflected inside the list. Here is how the script inside the PowerShell window:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Issue Tracking List is different from Custom List .
Where its default `WriteSecurity is 1` and can't be changed.

**The main reason for that** this list doesn't have an Item Permission Level in its Advanced settings List as Shown below.

[image]

**Not Like The Custom List Item Level Permissions Settings.**

[image]

**[Update as a workaround]**

- Create A custom list.
- go to advanced settings . > Allow content types.
- go to add an existing content types Select > list group > Issues.
- Set it as default.

[image]

- now you can use issue content type with a custom list as Issue Tracking List With Item Permission Level.

[image]

Comment: i know that this option is not available through the UI for issue tracking list. but i read other articles which mention that i can use powershell to set this http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/162303/contribute-without-delete-permission-which-allows-the-users-to-delete-their-ow/162308#162308 but not sure if the problem is with my script or issue tracking list & document library does not support this.Second question is there any drawbacks if i create a new custom list and add the same field as the issue tracking list, so i will get an issue tracking list with item-level permission?

Comment: Your script is correct, I tried it in custom list and working properly but with Issue list not working

Comment: so if i need this feature ,, i can create a new  custom list >> add the related fields found inside the issue tracking list... and i should be fine ... is this correct ?

Comment: any custom list with default item content type should be working properly, and what you say is considered a workaround solution :)

Comment: so in all ways i can not set this inside issue tracking or document library  ?  the strange thing is that i will not get any error inside the script , mentioning for example that the WriteSecurity property is not available or i can not be modified ... so i still have a feeling that there is a way to apply this to the issue tracking & document library lists...

Comment: the WriteSecurity property is available and it's default value is 1 but you can not modify it , to make sure that apply your command to a custom list will be updated  also Should you check my updated answer as workaround without creating columns again ,

Comment: it is really strange how sharepoint internally implement things!!,,, I mean why they do not allow Item-Level permissions on all lists !!!