# Where is the "Item Level Permissions" in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration

Usually it was : From the web site parameters --> Advances setting and it was the second option.
But I cant find it anymore. Where is this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the thing that is confusing you is that Sharepoint has different menus depending on whether you are looking at a Document Library, List or Task List.  (Please note all my screen shots are from SP 2013).

**List**  (please excuse me re-using the picture from my answer to your other question)

[image]

**Document Library**
[image]

**Task List**  (this is almost identical to a List - it looks as though the only difference is the 'email notification' option)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is usually occurring in case your current list is **`Issue Tracking`** List  (not custom list) where its default `WriteSecurity` is 1 and can't be changed so you will not find Item Level Permissions as shown below:

[image]

Check the workaround at [Modify the WriteSecurity property for an Issue Tracking List](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/191493/modify-the-writesecurity-property-for-an-issue-tracking-list/191500#191500)

Comment: Yes Im in a site collection

Comment: It is the same on all my sites